# Google App Engine - Image Clarity is reduced while using Image Service Factory for Resizing

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, resize, factory

I am using Image service factory for resizing images using Image Transform.

What I am doing is when they choose multiple images, i am getting the Image data of those images in Javascript and passing it to server to convert it to byte[] and and then creating a new Image out of it and resizing the image and getting the final resized image.

When i check it, the image is so blurred.

I have provided my code here. Check it and intimate me where Iam going wrong.

Thanks

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
Image original = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(imageByteArray);
Transform resize1 = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImFeelingLucky();
Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(width, height); 
CompositeTransform ct = ImagesServiceFactory.makeCompositeTransform();
ct = ct.concatenate(resize).concatenate(resize1);
Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, original);
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(newImage.getFormat().toString());
FileWriteChannel writeChannels =fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);
writeChannels.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(newImage.getImageData()));
writeChannels.closeFinally();
BlobKey croppedblobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
String ImageUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(croppedblobKey));
System.out.println("badgeImageUrl::"+ImageUrl.trim());
```

Comment: What are the `width` and `height` you are using above?  Also could you share an example of a blurred image?

Comment: we are passing only the original width and height which we are passing from Client

Comment: Yes, but what are some examples of these widths and heights? One possibility is that your client is passing values that are small, but displaying the images at a larger size -- which would make them look blurred.

Comment: Thanks for you time. If the original dimensions are 500 X 800, we are passing the same. We logged and saw the width and height. its the same width and heigh.